# IE8 vertical scrollbar problem

Tags: php, html, css, scroll

i have a problem in ie8, my site is [**http://www.2sinfotech.com/demo/guitar//**](http://www.2sinfotech.com/demo/guitar/)

when i click on join now or other link like faq. i didn't get vertical scrollbar in my site.
some time i get scroll or some time not.

Comment: EDIT: Spoke too soon - I was able to recreate the problem by clicking the Sign Up button on the Join Us page.
Looks fine to me in IE8.0.6001.  Clicked Join and FAQ links and vertical scroll bar was always present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your HTML through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org) and it's complaining about `<div class="wrapper">` not being closed before the closing `</body>`.  I would start with trying to get that fixed.

Comment: np - that's always my IE bug fixing process.  Validate the code and if it's still broken, make sure everything hasLayout...and if it's still broken...weep silent tears of fury.